# Build failed unexpectedly in jenkins build machine

Tags: ios, build, jenkins

I got this strange error and I can't figure out why I am getting it.

```
The following build commands failed:
    CompileC build/.../MyTarget.build/Objects-normal/armv7/ViewController.o 

ViewController.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
```

I can build the project with no warning locally on my mac, but on the jenkins build machine it is not working. Do you happen to know why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Compare logs, maybe different SDK versions or target processor architecture(armv7) are used ?
I had similar issue, in my case another architecture type was used by default.
Also try to set all the build parameters from command line to avoid using default values locally and on CI